how to initialize my values ​in my table declare with an _attribute__((section())), of a section in my linker script
`Hello everyone,
I'm new in that domain (linker script and memory section).
I have an array that I want to declare in a section of my address space of my processor (neorv32). I do this for various other reasons.
When I try to print my table I have totally different values
In my linker script, I declared a back (rwx): ORIGIN = 0xF0000000, LENGTH = 512K zone in the MEMORY{} zone i checked on the neorv32 documentation and the zone is one where i can write and read data.
Then in the SECTIONS{} area I have:
.background_section: ALIGN(4)
 {
 __background_start = .;
 KEEP(*(.background_section))
 __background_end = .;
 } > back

Then to initialize my table I did in a .c:
__attribute__((section(".background_section"))) uint32_t background[12] = {
 0xBDEBDEBD,0xEBDEBDEB,0xDEBDEBDE,
 0xBDEBDEBD,0xEBDEBDEB,0xDEBDEBDD,
 0xBDEBDDBD,0xDBDDBCDA,0xCDACDACD,
 0xBCDBCDBC,0xDBDDBDDB,0xDDBDDBDD};

size of 12 for the example but i got 122400 data
and when then in my main.c I want to print my values ​​from my array I see that I have values ​​that do not correspond to the initialized ones.
here is what I have in my .map:
.background_section
 0xf0000000 0x30
 0xf0000000 __background_start = .
 *(.background_section)
 .background_section
 0xf0000000 0x30 ./main.c.o
 0xf0000000 background
 0xf0000030 __background_end = .


here is the section header :
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00000000 001000 000ddc 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 2] .rodata           PROGBITS        00000ddc 001ddc 000310 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 3] .background_[...] PROGBITS        f0000000 003000 000030 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 4] .data             PROGBITS        80000000 003030 000000 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 5] .bss              NOBITS          80000000 003000 000074 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 6] .heap             PROGBITS        80000074 003030 000000 00   W  0   0  4
  [ 7] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 003030 00000f 01  MS  0   0  1
  [ 8] .riscv.attributes RISCV_ATTRIBUTE 00000000 00303f 000035 00      0   0  1
  [ 9] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS        00000000 003078 0001a0 00      0   0  8
  [10] .debug_info       PROGBITS        00000000 003218 002fe9 00      0   0  1
  [11] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS        00000000 006201 00091d 00      0   0  1
  [12] .debug_line       PROGBITS        00000000 006b1e 002e0a 00      0   0  1
  [13] .debug_frame      PROGBITS        00000000 009928 0004c8 00      0   0  4
  [14] .debug_str        PROGBITS        00000000 009df0 002131 01  MS  0   0  1
  [15] .debug_loclists   PROGBITS        00000000 00bf21 000c3b 00      0   0  1
  [16] .debug_rnglists   PROGBITS        00000000 00cb5c 0001aa 00      0   0  1
  [17] .debug_line_str   PROGBITS        00000000 00cd06 0002b1 01  MS  0   0  1
  [18] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 00cfb8 0013f0 10     19 274  4
  [19] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 00e3a8 00088e 00      0   0  1
  [20] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 00ec36 0000e6 00      0   0  1

and here is what I have with the command objdump -s -j .background_section :
 f0000010 ebbddeeb ddebbdde bdddebbd dabcdddb  ................
 f0000020 cddaaccd bccddbbc dbbddddb dddbbddd  ................```

Thank you for your feedback


Wouldn't it make more sense to turn the array const/read-only?

I will try.
what I was able to do before was to use pointers, making a dynamic and/or static allocation, but when I wanted to make a printf of my data.
Nothing was done on the FPGA, the board crashed.
I figured there must be a problem with the heap or stack so I tried to declare my own zone.

can you provide the section headers of the final executable using Readelf ?

@Giackkk i've posted a the section headers in a answer text, I don't know if it's the right place.

you have to use:
readelf -S main.elf or main.o
because I need to see the section flags (right now you're printing the symbol table) since I suspect that the problem could be there, also delete the answer and add the section headers in the question.

@Giackkk okay i'm doing it thanks

ok thanks, so section flags are ok, but the size of the section is different from it's real size (that should be 48 bytes), can you try to define the memory region (back) length to fit just the section length (so 48 bytes) and see how the section headers changes, and also can you print:  objdump -s -j .background_section to see what is inside the section

@Giackkk i hope i did what you suggest, and i add the objdump command

ok so now it has the correct data in the section, if you print it it should work.
Also if you modify the question leave the other changes, such as the old section headers with the original memory region definition (the 512k size one), because right now if you don't read the comments (to see that you changed your memory section length definition), so add that you edited your original question with these changes on the memory definition
